# Innodb_Buffer_Pool_Size Performance

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I need a real and clear definition about the innodb_buffer_pool_size. It is suppose to increase performance but I'm not sure how.

```
Operative System: Debian 8
Memory: 1468mb
Mysql 5.5
```

What i did for my test was to create a table with 750001 rows with the default innodb_buffer_pool_size=134217728 and I made it on 1min 17.01sec.

```
INSERT INTO luis_test3 SELECT * FROM luis_test;
Query OK, 750001 rows affected (1min 17.01 sec)
```

After that test, I changed innodb_buffer_pool_size=402653184 and made the insert to another table (empty table) and made it on

```
INSERT INTO luis_test2 SELECT * FROM luis_test;
Query OK, 750001 rows affected (2min 3.17 sec)
```

Seems it doubles the size and no performance was improve, maybe affected on the insert but I'm not sure where will I improve performance. By the way, i have to note that I restarted my service on each change.

I have a whole server with full MyIsam tables to Innodb, but I need to follow the right conventions to set up everything on Innodb. Actually I want to prepare it for make hot backups using Percona Xtrabackup (so MyIsam is not considered for my plan).
I copy my data table sizes:

```
table------------------test
luis_test             316.47
luis_test2            272.83
luis_test3            272.83
luis_test_myIsam      254.16
table_prueba            0.02
```

None of the tables are indexed.

Answer (score 0):

There are many more aspects to tuning than what you have mentioned.

The bottom line is pretty simple:

- Set innodb_buffer_pool_size to about 70% of *available* memory.  (That is, after allowing for other applications.)
- Set `key_buffer_size` to about `40M`.

To change from MyISAM to InnoDB is optimally just `ALTER TABLE t ENGINE=InnoDB`.

However, there are a lot of things that *may* cause degraded performance, especially in the way of indexes.  I have [*enumerated them*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb) and discussed them.  Probably very few will be critical.

The `ALTER TABLE` does virtually the same things as `CREATE TABLE ...; INSERT ... SELECT; RENAME TABLE ...`, just a lot shorter to type.

If, after studying my blog, you see the need to change the indexes, etc, then doing all the steps in a single `ALTER` is optimal:

```
ALTER TABLE t ADD PRIMARY KEY(foo), MODIFY COLUMN ..., ... ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Yes, you need to do one table at a time.

If you have a lot of large tables, it is best to set `innodb_file_per_table=ON` *before* doing the `ALTER` or `INSERT...SELECT`.

Why did one test take twice as long as the other?  Again, there are lots of things going on, so I can't give you a simple answer.  One deadly possibility: Was 402653184 so big that it led to swapping?  How much RAM do you have?  That number would probably be too big for a 2GB server.

Comment: So, changing key_buffer_size to 70% available memory will increase performance? how and what other performance will i see(insert, updates or just queries)?. I have a VM with 1468mb of memory for my test server.

Comment: NO!  `key_buffer_size` is only for MyISAM indexes.  If you are running MyISAM only, the recommendation is 20% of RAM for that.  [More discussion.](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory).  1468MB is tiny -- "available" memory is perhaps only 300MB; take the percentages of _that_.

Comment: What about InnoDB and my Question I started off?

Comment: Some of the factors that I need to know in order to explain the timing difference:  Where there indexes on the target table (`SHOW CREATE TABLE`)?  How big is the table (`SHOW TABLE SIZE`)?  (In particular is it bigger or smaller, including indexes, than the buffer_pool?)  Was there swapping?  (I suspect that caused the bigger buffer_pool to be slower.)

Comment: Rick, I don't have indexed the tables. I have updated my question so that you could see my table sizes by MB.

Comment: Are there a way to track out my server according to it know what's the best option to optimize it (innodb_buffer_pool_size,innodb_file_per_table, so on)?. I really want to optimize my server and Fernando Ipar (from Percona) mentioned that Innodb is better and faster than MyIsam but you need to know how to setup this complex engine and I'm researching about it. With an analogy it would be good to me.

Comment: Your benchmark is probably not representative of what your code will be doing.  If you have application-specific SQL, we can discuss that in more detail.